# How to get Azure TTS API for Anki with Postman

Tags: azure, api, text-to-speech, anki

I was trying to get API Key for AwesomeTTS (Anki)
I want to use Azure Text-to-Speech service REST API

I followed two YouTube videos (one is below and I can't find the other one right now)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcZF73bsme0

I only got an audio file, but I have no idea where is the API Key I need for ANKI.

I also read this article on Microsoft website many times
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech#authentication

Could anyone tell me where/how I could get the API Key?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Could anyone tell me where/how I could get the API Key?

You can get the API key by following steps:

- Create an account on https://portal.azure.com
- Create a Subscription which will have your billing information
- Create a Resource Group in East US
- Create a Speech Service entry
- In your Speech Service entry, your API key can be found under Resource Management -> Keys and Endpoint

You can refer to [Key creation](https://github.com/AwesomeTTS/awesometts-anki-addon/wiki/Microsoft-Azure-Text-to-Speech#key-creation), [API key to TTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/195764/api-key-to-tts.html) and [AwesomeTTS API keys](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anki/comments/omfs9m/comment/h5majr8/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)